# Which thread (UI/Background) does view model class of architecture components lives?

Tags: android, webrtc, android-architecture-components, android-viewmodel

I built a webrtc based calling app. All codes are in Activity as of now so as expected it doesn't work well on configuration changes. I'm thinking to put all WebRTC code to view model and update UI from view model. Do I've to do background tasks in separate thread in view model too like I did in activity. Currently I'm using java Thread in activity.

Comment: Yes you do. ViewModel does nothing special, look at the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `ViewModel` is just a class which instantiates along with an `Activity`/`Fragment`.
Going through threads is another case and has nothing to do with `Viewmodel`. Don't forget that if a class extends the `ViewModel` will have its' own [lifecycle](https://developer.android.com/images/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel-lifecycle.png).

> Do I've to do background tasks in separate thread in view model too
>   like I did in activity?

So the answer is YES. `Activity`, `Fragment`, `ViewModel`, `Presenter`, `Interactor` or whatever are just classes. You will jump to threads if performing asynchronous or heavy operations wherever you are. Even if we are not talking `Android` at all

Answer (score 1):

Of course you have to. `ViewModel` is just a class, it does not work in worker thread by default.